# Application Variable Vs Web.Config Variable

Tags: asp.net

Which is better from a performance perspective?

- Accessing a Global Application Variable (Application["foo"])

versus

- Accessing an AppSetting variable from the web.config

Does .NET Cache the AppSetting variables so that it is not accessing the web.config file with every use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two things are not comparable. `appSettings`, or any other configuration settings, are for *configuration* settings. `Application` variables are for quantities that might change during the course of the application, or are for things like tables of domain data values. These latter are things which you would not place into a configuration file, because they change rarely, and do not need to be configured.

`appSettings` and everything else in a config file, is cached. The file is only read once per AppDomain, in general. In fact, when you change your web.config, it causes an AppDomain restart, mainly so that the new configuration settings can be read in.

Answer (score 0):

appSettings [are apparently not cached](http://dotnetperls.com/cache-settings-aspnet)

EDIT: Seems both appSettings and Application variables would be the same speed then. After the initial load of course.

Comment: This is not true. Everything from a .NET configuration file is cached.

Comment: Ahhh yes. Seems I didn't read the article through to the bottom :)

Comment: Where in the article does it say the file is cached? As far as I can tell, the article simply proceeds from a false premise.