# ASP.NET Application variable vs reading from ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, global-asax

There is a similar question posted at [Application Variable Vs Web.Config Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560309/application-variable-vs-web-config-variable), but mine is slightly different and I'm not convinced with the answer there.

So, if I define an application variable in my global.asax like this:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{    
   public static readonly string X =  ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XsltExternal"];
   // rest of the code here
}
```

Shouldn't this read operation

```
string Y = Global.X;
```

be faster than

```
string Y = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XsltExternal"];
```

because of avoiding hashtable lookup (presuming that's how ASP.Net stores the web.config settings)? My application uses tons of config settings and checks for it throughout page cycle so I'm hoping I to take advantage of every single ms that I can save.

Thoughts anybody?

PS: My initial simple-test-page ANTS profiler test shows read time dropping from 0.017 ms to .002 ms.

Comment: Kind of yes, just want to confirm with others if there was anything I was not considering before I go and convert all those zillions of lines of code ..lol :-)

Comment: It will also be far easier to maintain a structured configuration class to handle your most common settings. You really should only make direct calls to AppSettings from inside your structured configuration class.

Comment: @Frazell, so what you are suggesting is to create a static object of this new class from Global instead of accessing these variables separately like NS.Global.VARNAME. Yes, makes sense. The only problem I'm facing is that in a multi-project solution I'm not able to access Global class and I can't add reference to my main project from other support projects as it creates cyclic dependency issue. Working on it!

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes, it is faster, but I would try to keep the Global class as clean as possible. In my implementations I usually put all my configuration items on a separate class with a static constructor, for example:

```
public class Constants
{
    public static string PayPalSeller;
    public static string PayPalUrl;
    public static string PayPalPDTKey;
    public static string RpxTokenUrl;
    public static string VirtualAppFolder;
    static Constants()
    { 
        PayPalSeller = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalSeller"];
        PayPalUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalUrl"];
        PayPalPDTKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalPDTKey"];
        RpxTokenUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RpxTokenUrl"];
    }
 }
```

To use it, of course you would go:

```
Constants.PayPalSeller
```

hope this helps,
-covo

Comment: Just for clarification, it would be a good idea to make the class itself static in this case.